# Number of group homomorphisms from quaternion group to itself.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, quaternions

I have to find all group homomorphisms from quaternion group $Q_8=\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j,\pm k\}$ to itself . I tried it as

Since $Aut(Q_8)\cong S_4$ so there are $24$ automorphisms which are also homomorphisms. One is trivial homomorphism which maps all elements to identity and there are $4$ homomorphisms whose range are inside $\{\pm 1\}$ as they are factor through $\frac{Q_8}{\{\pm 1\}}\cong \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2.$   Now there is  no onto maps from $Q_8$ onto $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$, $\{\pm 1,\pm j\}$, $\{\pm 1,\pm k\}$ as these are cyclic groups of order $ 4$ but $\frac{Q_8}{\{\pm 1\}}\cong \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has no element of order $4$. So I conclude that in  total there are $24+1( trivial)+3=28$ group homomorphisms.

Please comment if any mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct in my opinion.

Comment: @kabenyuk thank you.........

Answer (score 5):

See [Rajkumar](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXrOD3z6H0AhUc8LsIHWECCdM4FBAWegQIDxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fijmaa.in%2Fv3n3-a%2F23-30.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1gFpCLNTE0k32HnuPrk57v) for the number of homomorphisms $f\colon Q_{4m}\rightarrow Q_{4n}$ for the generalized quaternion groups. Theorem 2.4. shows that the number, for $m$ and $n$ even with $m\equiv 2\bmod 4$ is given by
$$
4+8n+2n\left( \sum_{k\mid (2m,2n),k\nmid m} \phi(k)\right).
$$

For $m=n=2$ this gives $28$ homomorphisms, as you have shown.

Comment: is it correct as i solved ?

Comment: This depends on the standards of grading, i.e., how much details you are supposed to give, and what you are allowed to use without further justification. How exactly does the nonexistence of these onto maps give you the final result? Since you are asking, I feel that you are still unsure of something.